# How to read Spotify's iOS endpoint reference?

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning Swift, and I am making an app that can create playlists on a user's account. I am getting an error where Xcode says that I am using too many arguments:

```
SPTPlaylistList.createPlaylistWithName(NSString(string:"hello"), 1, self.session, callback: {(error: NSError!, result: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        println("playlist created")
})
```

The Spotify endpoint reference guide states :

```
(void)createPlaylistWithName:(NSString *)name publicFlag:(BOOL)isPublic session:(SPTSession *)session callback:(SPTPlaylistCreationCallback)block
```

Where am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the problem that you pass in 1 as publicFlag? I wants a boolean.

Comment: nope, doesn't cut it...